# How to control parameter in method in java

Tags: java

I have a very easy question but I don’t know what. The sample code below

```
public class test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test = new test();
        int temp = test.method(0);
        System.out.println("temp = " + temp);
   }

   public int method(int i) {
        if (i < 7) {
           i++;
           method(i);
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

If I want **get 7 in the temp in the main** what can I do? Just use the other static parameter? or is there any way to achieve this one?

Comment: did you mean `return method(i);`?

Comment: dont quite understand your question

Comment: why is it even upvoted

Comment: if return method(i) will get StackOverflowError.

Comment: No, he/she means change `method(i);` to `return method(i);`.  Not the last line.

Comment: just use int temp = 7. what do you want?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira my guess is that he/she is learning about recursive methods in class.

Comment: oh i get it.. so, what's the problem? the recursive he/she have made will return 7. oh he's missing the return statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int method(int i) {
    if (i < 7) {
        i++;
        return method(i);
    } else {
        return i;
    }
}
```

should work fine :)

breakdown:

```
IF i is smaller than 7, increment i and return method(i) 
ELSE return i (must be 7)
```

the else block is optional:

```
public int method(int i) {
    if (i < 7) {
        i++;
        return method(i);
    } 
    return i;
}
```

but it's more clear if you have the else since it is conditional.

Comment: @apss1943 `return method(i)` returns to you, the value that is returned by calling `method(i)`. This is very simple java recursion, here is a basic lesson on it: [link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) This is basically the same as `return i`, where you return the value of i to wherever you call it from

Comment: You can assign a value that is returned from a method:

`int number = somemethodwithreturnvalue(10);`

Comment: thank you i miss the "return" if i wanna use recursion.